# How to correctly write a way for a user to contact me in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Contact Form]

I am unsure how to get the correct HTML and CSS for the Contact Me part of a mock resume contact form that I am trying to make. None of the information that I put in the input boxes will go anywhere, but I am just trying to create a mock Contact Me form.

When I tried my HTML and CSS, the button would not go below the last box. Also, I am unsure how to have the green background in the back, while there is text on top of it. I am still learning HTML and CSS would like an explanation if possible.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.contact-me {
    width: 700px;
    height: 81px;
    font-family: Bitter;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
}

.contact-item {
    width: 684.4px;
    height: 29px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.contact-box {
    width: 697.5px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 2px #b6b5b7;
    background-color: #fffefe;
}

.contact-reason {
    width: 391px;
    height: 29px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #575159;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.contact-reason-box {
    width: 698px;
    height: 248px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 2px #b6b5b7;
    background-color: #fffefe;
}

::placeholder {
    width: 672.7px;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #b8b8b8;
}

.button {
    width: 698px;
    height: 74px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-me">Contact Me</div>
<div class="contact-item">Your First Name:</div>
<input class="contact-box" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="John">
<div class="contact-item">Your Last Name:</div>
<input class="contact-box" type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Smith">
<div class="contact-item">Your Email Address:</div>
<input class="contact-box" type="text" name="email" placeholder="john@email.com">
<div class="contact-item">Your Phone Number:</div>
<input class="contact-box" type="text" name="number" placeholder="(732)555-0123">
<div class="contact-reason">Reason For Contact:</div>
<input class="contact-reason-box" type="text" name="contactReason">

<button class="button" type="submit">SEND</button>
```

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language. (Then search for introductory tutorials on using it, processing form data with it, and sending emails from it)

Comment: What do you mean by "the button would not go below the last box". When I run your code, the button is below the "Reason For Contact" box...

Comment: Typically, things like this are wrapped in a `form` element. that's what you'd give a green background too.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I found the fix on my end. And wrap everything in a form element?

Comment: That's what I would do. The HTML specification also says form elements (such as `input`) should be contained in a `form` or reference a `form` in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a pretty good start. I don't mean to completely take away the work that you've done so far, so I didn't want to re-write your code. However, with that being said, here are some answers to the questions you have and some tips on my own.

To get the background green, you'll want to set the `background:` or `background-color:` of your element to your color of choice. In the case of the image you sent, the background color is `#A0D199`, so you would add that to the CSS of your container. For the sake of simplicity, let's just set that to the body of the page since this is only the form that you're looking for. If you have a div or other content, you could set this same CSS to the respective container, even the form if you would like:

```
body {
  background: #A0D199
}
```

Speaking of form, it's a good idea to wrap your inputs into a form. As you progress in your coding and learn how to work with forms, this will become handy. Do this by added `<form> </form>` around your inputs.

Now onto the inputs, one change I made was instead of using a button property, I set an input with the type of "submit" (`<input class="button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">`) this accomplishes the same thing you had before but will likely work better with forms in the future. The text you would like will be in the "value".

Moving forward a little bit more, I took out some of your CSS:

```
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
```

These are all normal anyways, so you're just taking up lines of CSS by adding them. It's a good idea to use these if you're changing something, but if keeping them normal then you can omit.

Lastly, the issue you were having about the button not being at the bottom can likely be fixed by having this wrapped in a form, but also by adding the `display: block;` to the button CSS. Some of the most common 2 properties are "block" and "inline". Without getting much into detail, block lines things up vertically, and inline keeps everything in reading order (left to right in english). [Here's some more info about this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

So with all that being said, I've edited a fair amount of your CSS and a little bit of the HTML to get you on the right track.
[HERE YOU GO](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/XWJJjxx)

I may have done things in a way that others would do different, but tried hard to keep things as much as possible as you had done already with the code you provided. I think this is a good start for you on this form design. My recommendation would be to look this over well, see what I changed, and then try to re-create it on your own without looking at my version (just refer back to it if you forget something). Remember that you learn the most by doing, so good luck and let me know if you have any questions or would like clarification!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course, hope this helped. If this answer worked for you, please mark it as such when you can. Feel free to comment on here if you have any questions in the future. Good luck with your continued journey!!

Comment: I have another question. How would I be able to make the contact me form responsive? I have added padding to make sure the boxes and all the text are centered, but if I were to resize the browser, all of the boxes and texts are stuck in place. I thought display: flex would make it move around as I resize the browser?